# resume secondary activity on notification click, with timer still running

Tags: java, android

I am opening from my MainActivity the second activity TimerActivity which starts a countdowntimer from 100. In the onPause I have put in a Notification, so if the app goes to background it notifies the user that it is still active. What I would like to achieve is, when the user clicks the notification, the TimerActivity should open again and it should resume to the time it was counting down in the background. It should not restart from 100, but continue from 80 if the app was in background for 20 seconds.

Here is the MainActivity with only one Button:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonStart;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And here is my TimerActivity with 1 TextView only:

```
public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CountDownTimer timer;
int number = 100;
TextView text;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
Boolean notificationRunning = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gear_icon);
    builder.setContentTitle("Notification:");
    builder.setContentText("Timer is still running!");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    timer = new CountDownTimer(number * 60 * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            text.setText("" + number);
            number = number - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            text.setText("finish");
        }
    }.start();
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimerActivity.class);

    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    0,
                    notifyIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
            );

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationRunning = true;
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

protected void onResume(){
 super.onResume();
 if(notificationRunning){
     mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
     notificationRunning = false;
 }

}
}
```

I know I am missing some basic information, any help is greatly appreciated.

Update, if I am using an extra button from the MainActivity and following code, then it works as expected:

```
Intent openSecondActivity= new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimnerActivity.class);
                openSecondActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivityIfNeeded(openSecondActivity, 0);
```

And in my TimerActivity I am simply Overriding the onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This way, I start the app, click on Start button. The timer starts from 100. I click the back button and wait 10 seconds. Then I click the newly added Resume button and the TimerActivity gets to the front and the timer is at 90. So it resumed.

This is what I would like to achieve, but on the Notification click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution finally:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TimerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gear_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setPriority(2)
            .setContentText("Content text")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

This way, it resumes the counting, where it was it the background. Thanks for the help. They actually helped me bring to this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so when reopening the app from the notification you are losing the countdown. You can simply add the time as an extra to your `notifyIntent`

Comment: The countdowntimer is still running in the background, if I reopen the app from revent apps, it is fine. It starts not again from 100.

Comment: @Gexo the expected result is "It should not restart from 100, but continue from 80 if the app was in background for 20 seconds.". What is the actual result ? And you still need to use onSaveInstanceState because your activity can be killed by the system while it is in the bg

Comment: At the moment, when I click the notification, it restarts from 100. So basically it calls the onCreate. The expected result would be, to not call onCreate() and just continue it, only in the foreground. updating post in a second.

Answer (score 0):

You could store data that count time to [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) easily, if you don't want to use Service. You can use even after then `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life easier by storing the time when your timer should be finished (`System.currentTimeMillis() + number * 1000`). Save that into [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and restore your app state in `onResume()`

In onResume you would set

```
 Long endTime = savedInstanceState.getLong("endTime")
 int number = (int) (endTime - System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but if I would like to update the Notification with the timer, so display the seconds left in the notification, the time when it stops is not enough.

Comment: You can always infer the time left by subtracting the current time from the time where it stops.